# Gabriel's horn, calculus Integration

Tags: calculus, integration

Gabriel's horn is formed by revolving the curve $y=1/x$ for $x\in [1,\infty)$ about the $x$-axis.

Find the volume inside Gabriel's horn. I have the answer but I can't seem to get it right. Can someone explain please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you should do for finding the result is to evaluate the following integral $$\int_1^\infty \pi y^2 dx$$ in which $y=\frac{1}{x}$. You can draw a disc as you see in fig below. We build this disk on $x$- axes, so the volume of it is the volume of colored cylinder. What is that volume? It is $\pi r^2 h$. What is $r$ and what is $h$? indeed, $r$ is $y$ and $h$ is $dx$.

[image]

Comment: I completely forgot to multiply by pi. 
Thank you very much for your illustration, it was very helpful.

Comment: Awesome! Which software/program? ;-) +1

Comment: @amWhy: Maple is that one, dear.

Answer (score 0):

$$ x \, y = a^2$$

starting point  $(a,a)$

end point  $(\infty, 0)$

$$ \int_a^\infty { \pi y^2 \, dx} = \pi a^3 $$

which is $ \frac 34 $ th volume of sphere of radius $a.$